# Dependency Resulotion Source packages

Tags: linux

### Heading

I want to configure nbd-3.10.tar.gz package in red hat enterprise Linux.
first i unpacked this source package and successfully untar it and perform ./configure and finally it show me this message.
Could not run GLIB test program, checking why...
*** The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the**
 exact error that occurred. This usually means GLIB is incorrectly installed.
configure: error: Missing glib
I download the glib 2.26.0 version and wanted to configure it but during configuration it show me this message.
configure: error: 
 **You must have either have gettext support in your C library, or use the
*** GNU gettext library. (http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/gettext.html.
I download the gettext source package but it also depend to another packages.
please help me about this dependency and really it is boring to me because every package has dependency and in my CD and DVD of Linux these packages are not availabl and i download it from internet and guide me how to solve this dependency of packages from internet.

Answer (score 1):

There is standard package, named gettext for RHEL. Install it. As you need to compile something with gettext support you need to install dev packages to gettext

```
yum install gettext-devel
```

Comment: OK but my  problem was about dependency and i know the yum server but i install packages from internet and these packages are not available in CD of red hat that i have

Comment: Change your repo to CentOS and install them. If they do not exist download them one by one and test again and again. I do not know other (faster) way